# "synchronized" method vs. "synchronized (Class.class)"

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

I'm reading the `BluetoothChatService.java` file from Android sample and one thing in particular confuses me.

- There are multiple locations in which a method is accessing a **static member** and it is defined as **synchronized**.
- In another section, the same static member is being accessed but the
  Class-Level synchronization is used instead of a synchronized method.
- And also there is another method which is not synchronized but uses `synchronized(this)` instead.

Can somebody explain the reason for using different techniques?

Source code is available at [BluetoothChatService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/25b6aed7b2e01ce7bdc0dfa1a79eaf009ad178fe/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.java) and here are some snippets that I was talking about:

```
private int mState;

// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;      
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; 
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;
```

**synchronized method**:

```
public synchronized void start() {
             ...
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
             ...
}
```

**synchronized block (class-level)**:

```
if (socket != null) {
    synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_LISTEN:
            case STATE_CONNECTING:
            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
            mSocketType);
            break;
            case STATE_NONE:
            case STATE_CONNECTED:
            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
            try {
                socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**synchronized (this)**:

```
public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }
```

Comment: `synchronized(BluetoothChatService.this)` isn't class-level synchronization. It's synchronizing on the containing object of an inner class.

Comment: I don't see `synchronized (Class.class)` but rather `synchronized (Class.this)` which is a way to access the outer class instance from inside an inner class.

Comment: @user3580294, so these are all synchronizing on the same object, right?

Comment: @TavianBarnes, thanks. You are right. But why not using class-level sync since we are accessing a `static` member?

Comment: Based on a quick glance at the source, I think so, but I'd take that with a grain of salt, as it's possible I've missed something. It does appear to be that way though.

Comment: Because the field it is accessing is static final, and hence you are guaranteed to see the right value (provided the constructor finished). The field access you showed us does *not* need synchronization

Comment: It looks like it's synchronizing for `mState` which is an instance field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all cases lock is taken on current instance of `BluetoothChatService`.

1- `synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this)`

is used when code is written inside another class, can be an anonymous class inside `BluetoothChatService`. In order to refer to instance of `BluetoothChatService`.

2- `synchronized (this)`

is used inside any member function of BluetoothChatService. Which points to it's instance.

3- `synchronized void start()`

is used when entire method need to be synchronized.
it is equivalent to

```
void start(){ synchronized (this){
```

In first 2 cases other parts of the function(not inside synchronous block), do not require to be thread safe and putting a `synchronized` keyword before function name would make entire function thread safe, and as a result will make your app necessarily slow.

Comment: Thanks. But one question, how do you tell whether you need sync or not? For instance, why `public void write(byte[] out)` is not synced?

Comment: As a general rule you can say that if there is an object(or resource) that will be accessed by multiple threads then you need to synchronize all the code that reads or updates that object.

Comment: in case of mConnectedThread, in write method, is attribute of BluetoothChatService which is accessed by multiple threads so you only needed to synchronize the code that accesses mConnectedThread, "r" is a local variable here and will be created every time this method is called so doesn't need synchronization.